# AddattributetoFilter not working in list.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

Friends,

I have a situation,  I get the search results when I seaerch for e.g.  "Sunrise", but after I get the results I want to refine it further with another ATTRIBUTE value which is a TEXT field. IT is called att_eby_orientation and it has values "Portrait" and "Landscape", so in the URL can I add it like

http://crowdedgallery.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/index/?q=sunrise&orientation=Landscape

where the last varialbe is the **Attribute** with the Value **"Orientation"**.  I have a few more attributes to Filter like "Size",
 "color" etc,  so, I will be greatful if someone can help me to solve this issue

Comment: Is the attributes are enabled to filter in backend?